# Separating digits and numbers through Regex in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm working on Coordination converting APP in java.

I want to convert MGRS coordinates to decimals like `52SCG7250042500` or `5SDG7000050000`.

I want to separates or extracts the above coordinates like

```
52 S CG 72500 42500, 5 S DG 70000 50000...
```

How can I do this by using Regex expression?

This is my attempt, but it only returns number:

```
String aaa = "52SCG7250013500";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
//Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(aaa);
//Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(aaa);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    //System.out.println(m1.group());
}
```

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: String aaa = "52SCG7250013500";
  //System.out.println("Hello World!");
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
  //Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(aaa);
  //Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(aaa);


        while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
  //System.out.println(m1.group());
         }

Comment: the above on only returns number

Comment: http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Your Pattern specifies a number, so it returns a number. I don't see any genuine attempt to solve the problem yourself here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works correctly

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(mgrs);
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(mgrs);


    //initializing variables

    while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    }//end while

while (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group());
    }//end while
```